# Factors of $\binom{2^{q}}{2}-1$ and Wagstaff Primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

If $q$ is a prime number I write $$\mathfrak a(q) = \binom{2^{q}}{2}-1$$ Surely $\mathfrak a(q) =2^{q-1}(2^q-1)-1$. I would like to answer the following claim

> For every prime $q>2$ there exist an $n$ with $1\le n \le 5$ such that $3^nq\text{ }|\text{ }\mathfrak a(q)$

This is based on a hunch and computer checks. Also I suspect that the Wagstaff primes can occur as the largest prime factors of $\mathfrak a(q)$. The first prime to fail is $29$. In particular I am going to guess that

> For each prime $q$  there exist a Wagstaff prime $p$ such that $p\text{ }|\text{ }\mathfrak a(q)$.

Comment: Your last guess can't be true as written since $a(3)=2*7-1$ and there are certainly Wagstaff primes greater than that. You can easily show that $3|a(q)$ and $q|a(q)$ using modular arithmetic (that is with euler's theorem) but I don't have time to write an answer.

Comment: Hmm? $\mathfrak a(3) = 2^{2}(2^3-1) -1= 4*(8-1)-1=27$ and $3$ divides $27$ and $3$ is a Wagstaff prime. So you are wrong.

Comment: That's true but 43 is also a Wagstaff prime. Your statement as written would imply that 43 divides 27, which is impossible. In fact it implies any Wagstaff prime divides $a(q)$. I think you mean to say: For each $q$, there is a Wagstaff prime $p$ such that $a(q)$.

Comment: English is my second language but I am sure that I wrote. "If $p$ is a Wagstaff prime then $p$ divides $\mathfrak a(q)$. Isn't this the same as  - For each prime $q$ there is a Wagstaff prime $p$ such that $p$ divides $\mathfrak a(q)$?

Comment: ^ I see what you are saying now. I will correct and update the last guess.